# binding events to widgets

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I need to bind the button widget to the if statement and return the corresponding print statement to the screen (inside the result label)
here is the code I wrote:

```
from  tkinter import*
from functools import partial 
def call_result(event):
    temp=numberInput.get()
    if temp >22:
        print ("Increase")
    elif temp ==22:
        print ("reduce")
    else:
        print ("done")
        rLabel1.config(text="%d" %d)
    return

root=Tk()
numberInput=IntVar()
label_1= Label(root,text="Enter Temperature",fg="blue")
label_1.grid(row=0)
Temperature = Entry(root,bd=5)
Temperature.grid(row=0,column=1)
rLabel1= Label(root,text="Result",fg="blue")
rLabel1.grid(row=1, sticky=W)
call_out=partial(call_result,rLabel1,numberInput)
Button_1 = Button(root, text="OK", command=call_result)
Button_1.grid(row=0,column=2,columnspan=2)
root.mainloop()
```

Please correct me thanks.

Comment: what is the problem ? do you get error message ? always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot).

Comment: btw: `command=` executes function without arguments so you can't use `event` in `def call_result()` or you have to assign default value ie. `def call_result(event=None)`

Comment: instead `"%d" %d` you can use `str(d)` or rather `str(temp)`. In label you can even do `text=temp` or if you need with other text `text="Result %d" % temp` or `text="Result {}".format(temp)`

Comment: read: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: you get value from `numberInput.get()` but you didn' assign it to Entry ie. `tk.Entry(root, textvariable=numberInput)`. But you can also get text directly from `Entry` as text - `temp = int(Temperature.get())`

Answer (score 1):

I'm no magician but I'm pretty sure `(event)` isn't for commands done by tkinter made 'widgets'. So remove `(event)` from `def call_result(event):` and it should work perfectly as it did when I tried.

Comment: Sorry for bad English if I've misspelled anything